# Does there exist a fuchsian group that is not hyperbolic?

Tags: group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

Does there exist a fuchsian group that is not hyperbolic ?

By hyperbolic group I mean a group whose Cayley graph is hyperbolic in the sense of Gromov, and a fuchsian group is a discrete subgroup of PSL$_2(\mathbb{R})$.

The fuchsian groups that are cocompact are definitely hyperbolic, but maybe there exists a non cocompact fuchsian group that is not hyperbolic... maybe it could even be finitely generated.

Comment: If you write down the definitions of fuchsian and hyperbolic groups, then I will tell you the answer to your question. (For example, does your definition require a hyperbolic group to be finitely generated?)